# Generating proper options for select using ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Trying to get the options in the select field to use the IDs in an array as values.

HTML looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="activitySelector"
       ng-model="item"
       ng-change="changeActivity()"
       ng-options="activity.id as activity.value for activity in activities">
       <option value="">Nothing selected</option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('ActivityCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.activities = [
              {"id":"54be7f8","value":"Add New Activity"},
              {"id":"5407968","value":"Activity 1"}
        ];

        $scope.item = "";

        $scope.changeActivity = function() {
             console.log($scope.item); //prints undefined

        }


    });
```

Generated HTML looks like this:

```
 <select ng-options="activity.id as activity.value for activity in activities" ng-change="changeActivity()" ng-model="item" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid">
      <option value="" class="">Nothing selected</option>
      <option value="0">Add New Activity</option>
      <option value="1">Activity 1</option>
 </select>
```

Questions that I have so far: 
1- Why $scope.item prints undefined?
2- Why the options would use a consecutive value instead of the ID provided?

Comment: works fine in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2k5msgy8/)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code as follows in order for your html to render as you wish:

```
<select class="form-control" name="activitySelector"
   ng-model="item"
   ng-change="changeActivity()"
   ng-options="activity.value for activity in activities track by activity.id">
   <option value="">Nothing selected</option>
</select>
```

And in your controller now, you should change as follows:

```
$scope.changeActivity = function() {
    console.log($scope.item.id);
    console.log($scope.item.value); 
 }
```

Here is the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/DWobFzvas9x4lhaoNfTI.